# Как передать данные из формы в определённый кейс php ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Есть форма

```
<form id="create_gift">
<div class="form-group mb-1">
  <label for="new_pass">Подарочный код</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="code_price" id="code_price" placeholder="Какую сумму передать?" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group mt-3">
  <button class="cabinet-button" type="button" onclick="create_gift();">Создать gift-код</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Есть скрипт

```
function create_gift() {
let serialize = $('#create_gift').serialize();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/test/handler.php',
  data: 'operation=create_gift'+serialize,
  success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
 });
}
```

И нужно как-то передать в handler.php

```
$post = safedArray($_POST);
switch($post['operation'])
{
    case 'create_gift':
               $summ = intval($post['code_price']);
               ajax_html('success', $summ);
               break;
}
```

Нужно каким-то спосбом передать информацию из формы в hander.php. Через data: 'operation=create_gift'+serialize не работает, в консоли выводит пустую строку, а если изменить data, убрать +serialize и в ajax_html написать ('success', 'test');, то в консоль выведится {"type":"success","text":"333"}

Comment: А вопрос в чëм заключается? Проблема в чëм?

Comment: Нужно каким-то спосбом передать информацию из формы в hander.php, через data: 'operation=create_gift'+serialize не работает, в консоли выводит пустую строку, а если делать код без в data убрать +serialize и в ajax_html написать ('success', 'test');, то в консоль выведится test

Comment: Ну это не значит что в обработчик ничего не попадает, это значит как минимум, что с сервера ничего не приходит. А путь URL неизвестно какой у вас, вложенность структуры какой-то есть или нет, всё от корня считается или нет. Почему вы написали  `/test/handler.php`? test это что?

Comment: Прошу прощения, там нужно было изменить data
из
data: 'operation=create_gift'+serialize,
в
data: "operation=create_gift&"+serialize,

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается нужно было в data добавить один символ
из
data: 'operation=create_gift'+serialize,
преобразовать в
data: 'operation=create_gift&'+serialize,